# What do you call someone who is being escorted?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've heard of the term *escortee*, but Googling it doesn't turn up any definition.

If not that, then what could I use in this sentence:

> I escorted the girl through the school; she is a ________.

Comment: Is this a formal or informal escort?

Comment: In many businesses there are notices at reception that say "All visitors must be escorted", so you might say **I escorted the girl through the school; she is a visitor**

Comment: Chaperoned......

Answer (score 2):

*Escortee* appears to be a fairly modern word. A Google search for `define escortee` shows it's in

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/escortee)
- [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/escortee)
- [Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/escortee)
- [Wordsense](https://www.wordsense.eu/escortee/)
- [Definify](https://www.definify.com/word/escortee)

I stopped after five. All of those have "Someone who is escorted" as the basis of their definition.

Because it's recently-coined, most "mainstream" online dictionaries won't include it yet. Online dictionaries which are more geared towards user updates are more likely to include new coinages.

However, the *-ee* suffix is productive, and even without formal corroboration, *escortee* can be readily understood.

---

[Law Insider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/escortee) had a more specialised definition, presumably relating to a specific (although actually unspecified) situation:

> *Escortee* means the person who is being escorted and who must have government-issued photo identification on his or her person at all times when present within the Restricted Area or the Sterile Area.

Answer (score 1):

**Charge** is a possiblity, from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge) definition 3b:

> a person or thing committed into the care of another.

In the OP's example, we'd have "I escorted the girl through the school; she **was my** charge."